# first try packagist: Detection of execution by command (Terminal) or web environment

Tags: php, console

I'm here again; I'm learning a bit about github and posting things to packagist, this is my first try.

I have created a library that validates or verifies in what type of environment php is being executed, whether from a web environment or from a command terminal.

I appreciate if you can support me by giving it a look, and let me know your opinions about it (Opinion is understood as everything related to good practices based on PSR/symfony2 code style, security, distribution practice and anything else that comes to mind.).

Link: https://packagist.org/packages/arcanisgk/web-cli-detector

***WebCLIDetector.php (file)***

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace IcarosNet\WebCLIDetector;

/**
 * WebCLIDetector Class.
 */
class WebCLIDetector
{
    /**
     * Description: instantiate Class Static.
     * @var WebCLIDetector|null $instance
     */

    private static ?WebCLIDetector $instance = null;

    /**
     * Description: environment description.
     *  - CLI
     *  - WEB
     * @var string
     */
    private string $environment;

    /**
     * construct of class
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if ($this->evaluateEnvironment()) {
            $this->setEnvironment('CLI');
        } else {
            $this->setEnvironment('WEB');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEnvironment(): string
    {
        return $this->environment;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $environment
     */
    private function setEnvironment(string $environment): void
    {
        $this->environment = $environment;
    }

    /**
     * Description: Determinate if Running from Terminal/Command-Line Environment or Web by default.
     * @return bool
     */
    private function evaluateEnvironment(): bool
    {

        return defined('STDIN')
            || php_sapi_name() === "cli"
            || (stristr(PHP_SAPI, 'cgi') && getenv('TERM'))
            || (empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && count($_SERVER['argv']) > 0);
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCLI(): bool
    {
        return ($this->getEnvironment() === 'CLI');
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isWEB(): bool
    {
        return ($this->getEnvironment() === 'WEB');
    }

    /**
     * Description: Auto-Instance Helper for static development.
     */

    public static function getInstance(): WebCLIDetector
    {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

}
```

***Implementation on index.php***

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use IcarosNet\WebCLIDetector\WebCLIDetector;

require_once __DIR__."/../vendor/autoload.php";

$wc_detector = new WebCLIDetector();

if ($wc_detector->isCLI()) {
    echo 'Running from CLI'.PHP_EOL;
}

if ($wc_detector->isWEB()) {
    echo 'Running from WEB<br>';
}

echo 'Get Raw Environment: '.$wc_detector->getEnvironment();
```

[Update to v1.0.4](https://packagist.org/packages/arcanisgk/web-cli-detector)

Comment: Fixed distribution package now.

Answer (score 1):

Given you stated "*Opinion is understood as everything related to good practices based on PSR/symfony2 code style, security, distribution practice and anything else that comes to mind.*" I decided to check how well it adheres to [the PSR-12 Extended Coding Style guide](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) so I pasted the code from WebCLIDetector.php into [WebCodeSniffer.net](https://www.webcodesniffer.net/), selected *PSR-12* and this was the result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 6 ERRORS AFFECTING 5 LINES
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | ERROR | [x] End of line character is invalid; expected "\n" but
    |       |     found "\r\n"
 15 | ERROR | [x] Expected at least 1 space after "?"; 0 found
 40 | ERROR | [x] Expected at least 1 space before ":"; 0 found
 89 | ERROR | [x] Parenthesis must be used when instantiating a new
    |       |     class
 95 | ERROR | [x] Expected 1 newline at end of file; 0 found
 95 | ERROR | [x] The closing brace for the class must go on the next
    |       |     line after the body
----------------------------------------------------------------------
PHPCBF CAN FIX THE 6 MARKED SNIFF VIOLATIONS AUTOMATICALLY
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Time: 439ms; Memory: 4Mb
```

So there are only a few errors in terms of stylistic things. I didn't really notice those in my initial scan of the code. I did notice The last docblock does not include `@return` though the method has a return type and a `return` statement:

> /**
> * Description: Auto-Instance Helper for static development.
> */

One could declare constants for the strings used frequently - e.g. `'CLI'` and `'WEB'` - that should avoid mistakes like spelling or casing issues. For example:

```
class WebCLIDetector
{
    private const ENVIRONMENT_CLI = 'CLI';
    private const ENVIRONMENT_WEB = 'WEB';
```

The code within the constructor could be simplified from this:

> ```
> if ($this->evaluateEnvironment()) {
>     $this->setEnvironment('CLI');
> } else {
>     $this->setEnvironment('WEB');
> }
> ```

To simply:

```
$this->setEnvironment($this->evaluateEnvironment() ? 'CLI' : 'WEB');
```

Obviously if constants were used that line would likely be somewhat longer but perhaps not by very much. If it did become too long for a single line then it could be split into multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks guys, I made some changes already in v1.0.2 but I didn't manage to remove all the bugs found for the PSR-12 version; at the moment from the web tool that you have shared with me.

Comment: One of the problems that I could not solve was the line break since in my local I have it in \n but for some reason the web detects it as \r\n

Comment: That might just be an issue of new lines being interpreted as [`CRLF` instead of just `LF`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CRLF) - which [seems to come from the HTML 4 spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14217315/1575353). An alternative is to use an analysis tool within a native IDE.